# how do I do a try and except statement with this selenium error

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, pycharm

I am not sure how to take this selenium/webdriver exception and create a try/except/else statement with the following exception line. The website im scraping sometimes may not contain the element im looking for but I would like to address that exception and move on.

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable

Ive tried some variations of that line in my except statement to no avail.

```
def planCosts():
    driver.get("https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Samsung/Galaxy_S10+?sku=887276301570&planSku=Freedom%20250MB")

    MSRP = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.cKlhCz')))
    MSRP = MSRP[0].text
    MSRP = re.findall(r'\d+', MSRP)
    MSRP = int(MSRP[0])
    print(MSRP)

    # grabbing the lowest upfront payment from string of min and max
    try: # checks to see if element exist
        upfrontPaymentRaw = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.col-lg-6 .fTfebt')))

        upfrontPayment = upfrontPaymentRaw[0].text

    except selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: #if I get an error looking for it then just make it default number above(MSRP)
        myTabCharge = MSRP

    else: #if no error run this code
        upfrontPayment = re.findall(r'\d+', upfrontPayment)
        upfrontPaymentLowest = int(upfrontPayment[0])
        upfrontPaymentHighest = int(upfrontPayment[1])

        myTabCharge = (upfrontPaymentHighest - upfrontPaymentLowest) / 24
```

im hoping to be able to have a try/except/else statement that opens the browser, looks for that element, if it returns an exception that states the element is there then the variable i was looking to store it into will be this default number. Then continue running the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need that exception type in your namespace in order to catch it, so add to your imports:

`from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException`

And then try changing your except statement to:

```
except WebDriverException as e:
    if e.msg.strip().endswith("chrome not reachable"):
        myTabCharge = MSRP
    else:
        raise
```

That way you're only catching the specific exceptions you want to bypass, and raising anything else.

Comment: Hello Silver, appreciate your help. I have implemented what you have suggested. unfortunately I now get an error:

NameError: name 'WebDriverException' is not defined

Comment: Ah, no problem. Python needs the type in your namespace in order to check against it.  See my edit

Comment: one more hurdle perhaps?

AttributeError: 'WebDriverException' object has no attribute 'message'

Comment: Huh, maybe that could be a Python version difference between us? Try `msg` instead